# How to add an action to one of Eclipse's context menus?

Tags: eclipse, contextmenu

I'd like to enhance one of the context menus and add my private actions. Is that possible?
If so, can you provide instructions?
Can I fire an EXE which is not Java-based (but .NET ... )?

Comment: Can you give more detail please? "add my private actions" means what exactly ?

Comment: This article might be helpful: [Contributing Actions to the Eclipse Workbench](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html)

Comment: Yes. The "private action" means an executable that made by us (no Java based but Winforms-based)